# How to get an environmental variable to persist on Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, file, environment-variables, profile

This is my first question on Stack Overflow so I apologize in advance if it is a poor question.

I am just starting to learn how to program (starting off with Python). I am on a windows computer but I have installed Bash and Ubuntu because that is what my programming book told me to do. With that being said, I am trying to simply get an environmental variable I created in File Explorer to show in Bash. I went to my profile via the c disk and then users and then created a file called ".profile" which was a text document. In the text document the first line was export x=100. When I close and reopen Bash and then type "echo $x," nothing shows up. The next line is blank whereas I am trying to make it show 100. Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: `.profile` is only executed when you login, not for all shells.  So logout and log back in.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

In your home directory the `~/.bashrc` file for the user you are logged in as, you can add a variable on a new line in this file and save. The next time this file is loaded as this user, the variable should be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

In bash, you can export any environment variable with the following syntax:

```
export FOO=bar
```

In order to make these env variables available in your shell or in any other script, you need to `source` the file where you stored your variables:

```
source my_file
echo $FOO
```

You may refer to this article for additional examples:
https://linuxize.com/post/bash-source-command/

Usually the shell programs allow you to source a profile file.
For ubuntu, you can refer to this askubuntu question to learn more on how to setup your shell https://askubuntu.com/questions/566399/why-isnt-profile-sourced-when-opening-a-terminal